# Standard variable naming convention for the viewing user (as opposed to the user being viewed)

Tags: naming-conventions

In a system with multiple users, where it's possible for a user to view another user's details, the code will have to refer to the "viewer" and "viewee" users regularly.

Is there any convention I can use that would allow for unambiguous consistency in the code?

For example, imagine calling a method that returns a list of interactions between the current user and the user being viewed:

```
interactions = getInteractions(myUserId, otherUserId)
interactions = getInteractions(viewerUserId, vieweeUserId)
interactions = getInteractions(observerUserId, otherUserId)
interactions = getInteractions(thisUserId, thatUserId)
interactions = getInteractions(sourceUserId, targetUserId)
```

None of these are very satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you select one way, be consistent, and document what each naming convention is for then you have to be satisfied. I had the same problem then I noticed the ambiguity lessened and others on my team started to use those terms.

I like "er" and "ee" because the endings are consistent across numerous words, such as payer/payee, employer/employee, and so on. Interesting is http://www.worldwidewords.org/articles/ee.htm.

#### Comments

- For developers, source and target are nice because they are the same number of characters and we understand the terms.
- Better is Observee instead of Other for Observer, but it still not right.
- This / That for C# and My / Their for VB.Net